# database connectivity of phonegap application to mysql server

Tags: php, mysql

I just recently completed my mobile app using jquery and ajax and it runs perfectly on my web browser but when I compile it using phone gap. However the database connectivity is not working.

I have created a helper class which has all the php code for the database connectivity. When I am running my app **the whole query** is being seen instead of the result.

Please help.

My helper class has the following code:

```
class helper
{
  private $con;
  function __construct()
  {
    $this->con= new mysqli("192.168.1.22","root","","rmoce");
  }
  function __destruct()
  {
    $this->con->close();
  }
  function insert($table,$field,$value)
  {
    $str=" insert into $table($field) values($value) ";
    $this->con->query($str) or die($this->con->error);
  }
  function delete($table,$condition)
  {
    $str= "delete from $table where $condition";
    $this->con->query($str);
  }
  function update($str)
  {
    $this->con->query($str);
  }
  function select($field,$table,$condition)
  {
    $str="select $field from $table where $condition";
$result= $this->con->query($str) or die($this->con->error);
if ($result->num_rows==0)
{
  return "no";
}
else
{
  while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
  $data[] = $row;
}
return $data;
  }
}

$obj= new helper();
```

When I run the application I see the whole query itself. Please help.

Comment: the helper class has to be on a server, and you connect from the app to the helper using ajax

Comment: yup i have used ajax for fetching the data however i am using my computer as the server itself therefore i have written the ip address of my computer after connecting it to a wifi connection, however i am getting the same error. please help!!!!

Comment: can you provide the code you use for the ajax connection?

Comment: hy sorry just saw ur message here is the code for ajax:

Comment: sorry here is the code >$.ajax
   (
   {
   type:"post",
   url:"192.168.1.22//table.php",
   data:"cust1="+cust+"&osys1="+osys+"&hset1="+hset+"&syear="+year+"&smonth="+month+"&sdate="+date+"&eyear="+eyear+"&emonth="+emonth+"&edate="+edate
   +"&shour="+hour+"&sminute="+minute+"&ehour="+ehour+"&eminute="+eminute,
   success:function(response)
   {
    $("#mainright").html(response);
   }
  });